# How to trigger @CanExecute method on TableViewer selection change

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

i have a Part with toolbar and there is also a TableViewer.
Int toolbar i have an edit button, which should be active only when a row in table viewer is selected.

i have added a condition to handler's canExecute method.
i can see that this method executes when i click some buttons, but it does not execute when selection in TableViewer is changed, so it does not recognize that the edit button in toolbar should activate.

Maybe i can trigger an exucution of @CanExecute when selection in TableViewer is changed or maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute the handler using:

```java
@Inject
ECommandService commandService;

@Inject
EHandlerService handlerService;

...

ParameterizedCommand command = commandService.createCommand("command id", Collections.emptyMap());

if (handlerService.canExecute(command)) {
  handlerService.executeHandler(command);
}
```

"command id" is the id of the command that your handler is handling.

You can request that the tool bar be updated using:

```java
@Inject
IEventBroker eventBroker;

...

eventBroker.send(UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC, UIEvents.ALL_ELEMENT_ID);
```

Comment: Eclipse shows me that the access is discouraged and is not injecting anything

Comment: The discouraged message is OK, parts of the e4 API are not finalized so you have to suppress the warning.  You must run this code in a class which is injected (such as a Part) or pass the services as parameters to your code.

Comment: ok, you have written how to run canExecute and execute methods manually but how can i now refresh the toolbar?